# Missing first item of ListView after screen gets full

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

The first item of the listview get lost after screen fills with rows at time of scroll needed. Till 7 or 8th item the first row is visible but after 8th row it gets missing. After scroll starts everything gets normal except the first row lost. Below is the code looking for help.

```
public class ProfileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Results> {


private Context mContext;

public ProfileArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Results> resultsArrayList) {
    super(context, resource, resultsArrayList);
    this.mContext =context;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView questionIdView;
    TextView testTypeView;
    TextView correctAnswerCountView;
    TextView wrongAnswerCountView;
    TextView emptyAnswerCountView;
    TextView testDateView;
    TextView successRateView;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View convertView = view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Results results = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.overall_summary_template, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.questionIdView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overall_question_id);
        viewHolder.testTypeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overall_test_type);
        viewHolder.correctAnswerCountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overall_correct_answer);
        viewHolder.wrongAnswerCountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overall_wrong_answer);
        viewHolder.emptyAnswerCountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overall_empty_answer);
        viewHolder.testDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overall_test_date);
        viewHolder.successRateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.success_rate);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String testId = " #" + results.getItemTestIdString();
    viewHolder.questionIdView.setText(testId);
    String testType = results.getItemTestType();
    viewHolder.testTypeView.setText(testType);
    String testDate = results.getItemTestDate();
    viewHolder.testDateView.setText(testDate);
    String wrongOnesText = mContext.getString(R.string.wrong_summary);
    String falseOnes = wrongOnesText + String.valueOf(results.getItemNumberOfFalseAnswers());
    viewHolder.wrongAnswerCountView.setText(falseOnes);
    String emptyOnesText = mContext.getString(R.string.empty_summary);
    String emptyOnes = emptyOnesText + String.valueOf(results.getItemNumberOfEmptyAnswers());
    viewHolder.emptyAnswerCountView.setText(emptyOnes);
    String correctOnesText = mContext.getString(R.string.correct_summary);
    String correctOnes = correctOnesText + String.valueOf(results.getItemNumberOfCorrectAnswers());
    viewHolder.correctAnswerCountView.setText(correctOnes);
    String successRate = "% " + results.getItemSuccessRate();
    viewHolder.successRateView.setText(successRate);
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: Please check whether toolbar dont get overlap on listviews first item.

Comment: It shows the first item until the screen gets full, so if the problem is with the toolbar I guess it shouldnt show anytime. But thanks for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override two methods `getItemId()` and `getItemViewType()` in the adapter itself ..and make both of them return the default return statement (position) and check.

Comment: Unfortunately did not help, still 1st row gone after 8th row.   `@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }`

Comment: send the screenshot please

Comment: This is before the last row fits the screen https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_dZXm9rCL6-gbcLoGq4s9OkGh9Elvmvy, this is after first row lost https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uiNv_Vy_yBKXqJGcumXNTtQ0brvwQU42

Comment: either reduce the height of your row layout..of listview.(are you giving it a fixed height) if its already reduced ..then try ` fit systemswindow` to true of listview

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using constraintLayout, and constraining the bottom. I changed layout to LinearLayout, problem solved.